# High memory usage with Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-8.1-upgrade

Since I upgraded to Windows 8.1 I'm experiencing a frustrating issue with memory. My pc has 32 gb that end up all used by a ghost process.

If I look into the task manager I cannot see any process taking so much memory. I've used Poolmon to get the tag with more bytes and diff and I've found that CMNb tag is the one with a higher difference between Allocs and Frees.

Anyone has found this issue too? I've also used RAMMap and I've learnt that if I empty current working sets the memory reduces to minimum.

It's important to note that all this happens without running any specific software in the pc. Just waiting is enough to see how system degrades until a blue screen.

Any ideas of what is this CMNb tag?

Thanks!

Comment: CMNb - nt!cm        - Configuration Manager Name Tag. You can find a list of pool tags in pooltag.txt in the Debugging Tools folder.

Comment: do you use Avira Antivir? This can cause it. In xperfview/wpa you can see this: http://tinyurl.com/CmnbAvira

Comment: I made a Clean Boot and discovered that the service that was causing the memory consumption was Intel(R) PROSet Monitoring Service. I've disabled it and all it's working fine now.

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w8itproperf/thread/f7c50e6c-dea2-4b45-94ec-6ca65b150353/#fa4d16e3-956b-49d9-b6c8-01ded2fb8b40